# Error when attaching unsaved workbook

Tags: vba, excel, email

I have created a macro to send automated emails.

There is an error with the attachment. I create the attachment myself.

What I want as an attachment is the worksheet ws1, which, from reading in blogs, should be an entire workbook(file) to be an attachment.

I do not save the workbook that I create. I want the created workbook to be deleted after I send the mails, that is the reason for the piece of code at the end.

```
Sub EmailsNewReport()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New Report")
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets(1)

ws1.Cells.Copy
With ws2
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlValues
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlFormats
End With

ws1.Activate
ToArray = "aaa@gmail.com"
Subject = "Hello"
Content = "Hey"
ws1.Range("B3:P31").Select
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With Sheets("New Report").MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = Content
    .Item.To = ToArray
    .Item.Subject = Subject
    .Item.attachments.Add (wb.FullName)
    .Item.Send
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ws2.Parent.Close False
Set ws2 = Nothing

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily save the workbook somewhere, and attach the file with complete path and delete the file after sending the mail with attachment.